# Reusing Entities on symfony bundle

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm creating a Symfony2 bundle to be used in several projects ( right now 4 )
This bundle contains business logic that will be used across all projects.

The bundle has several abstract classes marked with **@MappedSuperclass** and all relationships between them are specified via interfaces and resolved with **addResolveTargetEntity**. Meaning
that I can override any entity in my bundle via configuration.

Now the thing is that although really cool, in all the projects that use this bundle I have to redefine all entities extending from the base one and configure them ( so they are real entities). It would be awesome if could make doctrine use the base entity if another is not provided/configured. Since not all need to be customized but all entities are used.

What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out the [SyliusResourceBundle](https://github.com/Sylius/SyliusResourceBundle) and more specifically the [LoadMetadata subscribers](https://github.com/Sylius/SyliusResourceBundle/blob/master/EventListener/LoadORMMetadataSubscriber.php).

These essentially allow you to create a load of classes with associations that can be converted into mapped superclasses if they are not the final child class. It also move the associations to the child class as they can't be present on a mapped superclass.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I need, many thanks to you sir :)